# How to skip printing elements already handled by XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

I've this input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<rootElem version="0.1">
    <elementSet name="ES1">
        <element name="E1">
            <item id="i1" value="1" enabled="true">
                <properties/>
            </item>
            <item id="AAA" value="AAA - BBB" enabled="true">
                <properties>
                    <entry>
                        <key>someKey</key>
                        <value>1</value>
                    </entry>
                </properties>
            </item>
            <item id="DistinctTitle" value="title1" enabled="true">
                <properties/>
            </item>
            <other id="id1" value="a" enabled="true">
                <properties/>
            </other>
        </element>
    </elementSet>
  <elementSet name="ES2">
    <element name="E2">
      <item id="i2" value="2" enabled="true">
        <properties/>
      </item>
      <item id="AAA" value="AAA = CCC" enabled="true">
        <properties>
          <entry>
            <key>someKey</key>
            <value>2</value>
          </entry>
        </properties>
      </item>
      <item id="DistinctTitle" value="title2" enabled="true">
        <properties/>
      </item>
    </element>
  </elementSet>
</rootElem>
```

and I'm applying this stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:variable name="temp">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="/" mode="phase1"/>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*" mode="phase1">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" mode="phase1"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@version[parent::rootElem]">
        <xsl:attribute name="version">
            <xsl:value-of select="'0.2'"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="element" mode="phase1">

        <xsl:variable name="elementSetName" select="../@name"/>
        <xsl:variable name="elementName" select="./@name"/>

        <xsl:variable name="DistinctTitle_value">
            <xsl:value-of select="child::item[@id='DistinctTitle']/@value"/>
        </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:variable name="candidates" select="'AAA BBB CCC'"/>

        <xsl:for-each select="current()/item">
            <xsl:variable name="itemName">
                <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
            </xsl:variable>

            <xsl:if test="contains(concat(' ', $candidates, ' '), concat(' ', $itemName, ' '))">
                <xsl:variable name="itemNameNew">
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat($DistinctTitle_value, '-', $itemName)"/>
                </xsl:variable>

                <item>
                    <xsl:attribute name="id">
                        <xsl:value-of
                            select="$itemNameNew"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>

                    <xsl:attribute name="value">
                        <xsl:call-template name="string-replace-all">
                            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="@value" />
                            <xsl:with-param name="candidates" select="$candidates" />
                            <xsl:with-param name="DistinctTitle_value"  select="$DistinctTitle_value" />
                        </xsl:call-template>
                    </xsl:attribute>

                    <xsl:attribute name="enabled">
                        <xsl:value-of select="@enabled"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="properties"/>
                </item>
                <xsl:message terminate="no">
                    <xsl:if test="$elementSetName != ''">
                        <xsl:value-of select="$elementSetName"/>
                        <xsl:text> - </xsl:text>
                    </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$elementName"/>
                    <xsl:text> : </xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$itemName"/>
                    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"> -> </xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$itemNameNew"/>
                </xsl:message>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="string-replace-all">
        <xsl:param name="text"/>
        <xsl:param name="candidates"/>
        <xsl:param name="DistinctTitle_value"/>

        <xsl:variable name="current">
            <xsl:value-of select="tokenize($candidates, ' ')[1]"/>
        </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$current != ''">
                <xsl:variable name="target">
                    <xsl:value-of
                        select="concat($DistinctTitle_value, '-', $current)"/>
                </xsl:variable>

                <xsl:call-template name="string-replace-all">
                    <xsl:with-param name="text" select="replace($text, $current, $target)"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="candidates" select="replace(substring-after($candidates, $current), '^\s*(.+?)\s*$', '$1')"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="DistinctTitle_value" select="$DistinctTitle_value"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="$temp"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="some $i in $temp//@id satisfies $i = ./@id">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="(following-sibling::*)[1]"/>
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

What I get is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rootElem version="0.2">
  <elementSet name="ES1">
    <element name="E1">
      <item id="i1" value="1" enabled="true">
        <properties/>
      </item>
      <item id="AAA" value="AAA - BBB" enabled="true">
        <properties>
          <entry>
            <key>someKey</key>
            <value>1</value>
          </entry>
        </properties>
      </item>
      <item id="DistinctTitle" value="title1" enabled="true">
        <properties/>
      </item>
      <other id="id1" value="a" enabled="true">
        <properties/>
      </other>
    </element>
  </elementSet>
  <elementSet name="ES2">
    <element name="E2">
      <item id="i2" value="2" enabled="true">
        <properties/>
      </item>
      <item id="AAA" value="AAA = CCC" enabled="true">
        <properties>
          <entry>
            <key>someKey</key>
            <value>2</value>
          </entry>
        </properties>
      </item>
      <item id="DistinctTitle" value="title2" enabled="true">
        <properties/>
      </item>
    </element>
  </elementSet>
</rootElem>
<item id="title1-AAA" value="title1-AAA - title1-BBB" enabled="true">
  <properties>
    <entry>
      <key>someKey</key>
      <value>1</value>
    </entry>
  </properties>
</item>
<item id="title2-AAA" value="title2-AAA = title2-CCC" enabled="true">
  <properties>
    <entry>
      <key>someKey</key>
      <value>2</value>
    </entry>
  </properties>
</item>
```

but I wanted for `item`s that were transformed (after matching their `id` to one of `candidates`) to be replaced inline, not coppied as original in place and then appended after the rootElem as transformed.

So, this is the desired output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rootElem version="0.2">
  <elementSet name="ES1">
    <element name="E1">
      <item id="i1" value="1" enabled="true">
        <properties/>
      </item>
      <item id="title1-AAA" value="title1-AAA - title1-BBB" enabled="true">
        <properties>
          <entry>
            <key>someKey</key>
            <value>1</value>
          </entry>
        </properties>
      </item>
      <item id="DistinctTitle" value="title1" enabled="true">
        <properties/>
      </item>
      <other id="id1" value="a" enabled="true">
        <properties/>
      </other>
    </element>
  </elementSet>
  <elementSet name="ES2">
    <element name="E2">
      <item id="i2" value="2" enabled="true">
        <properties/>
      </item>
      <item id="title2-AAA" value="title2-AAA = title2-CCC" enabled="true">
        <properties>
          <entry>
            <key>someKey</key>
            <value>2</value>
          </entry>
        </properties>
      </item>
      <item id="DistinctTitle" value="title2" enabled="true">
        <properties/>
      </item>
    </element>
  </elementSet>
</rootElem>
```

My bet is on this part:

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="some $i in $temp//@id satisfies $i = ./@id">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="(following-sibling::*)[1]"/>
        </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

but I can't get it to work... Any ideas, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have modified your current style sheet to:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:variable name="candidates" select="'AAA BBB CCC'"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="rootElem">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:attribute name="version">
                <xsl:value-of select="'0.2'"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="item[contains(concat(' ', $candidates, ' '), concat(' ', @id, ' '))]">
        <xsl:variable name="elementSetName" select="ancestor::elementSet/@name"/>
        <xsl:variable name="elementName" select="parent::element/@name"/>

        <xsl:variable name="DistinctTitle_value">
            <xsl:value-of select="../item[@id='DistinctTitle']/@value"/>
        </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:variable name="itemName">
            <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
        </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:variable name="itemNameNew">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat($DistinctTitle_value, '-', $itemName)"/>
        </xsl:variable>

        <item>
            <xsl:attribute name="id">
                <xsl:value-of
                    select="$itemNameNew"/>
            </xsl:attribute>

            <xsl:attribute name="value">
                <xsl:call-template name="string-replace-all">
                    <xsl:with-param name="text" select="@value" />
                    <xsl:with-param name="candidates" select="$candidates" />
                    <xsl:with-param name="DistinctTitle_value"  select="$DistinctTitle_value" />
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:attribute>

            <xsl:attribute name="enabled">
                <xsl:value-of select="@enabled"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:copy-of select="properties"/>
        </item>
        <xsl:message terminate="no">
            <xsl:if test="$elementSetName != ''">
                <xsl:value-of select="$elementSetName"/>
                <xsl:text> - </xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:value-of select="$elementName"/>
            <xsl:text> : </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="$itemName"/>
            <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"> -> </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="$itemNameNew"/>
        </xsl:message>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="string-replace-all">
        <xsl:param name="text"/>
        <xsl:param name="candidates"/>
        <xsl:param name="DistinctTitle_value"/>

        <xsl:variable name="current">
            <xsl:value-of select="tokenize($candidates, ' ')[1]"/>
        </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$current != ''">
                <xsl:variable name="target">
                    <xsl:value-of
                        select="concat($DistinctTitle_value, '-', $current)"/>
                </xsl:variable>

                <xsl:call-template name="string-replace-all">
                    <xsl:with-param name="text" select="replace($text, $current, $target)"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="candidates" select="replace(substring-after($candidates, $current), '^\s*(.+?)\s*$', '$1')"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="DistinctTitle_value" select="$DistinctTitle_value"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Template that removes item with @id='DistinctTitle' -->
    <xsl:template match="item[@id='DistinctTitle'][../item[contains(concat(' ', $candidates, ' '), concat(' ', @id, ' '))]]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

So far I have achieved your required output. I do not know if there will be problems in your implementation.

Comment: @joel-m-lamsen One thing that still bothers me (which I failed to mention) is how can I omit the whole `<item id="DistinctTitle" value="title1" enabled="true">...</item>` if there's at least 1 match of the `item[contains(...)]`?